# Formatting input value as user types

Tags: javascript, format, numeral.js

I am having difficulty updating an input fields value to currency while a user types. When I use the input event change I am able to successfully update the value to currency. But when I use **keyup** **event** the input value and interaction behavior is not very user friendly.

I tried using a setTimeout but I can't achieve the value/currency formatting as the user types correctly.

**Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.**

**Example:**

```
myInputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
 e.currentTarget.value = numeral(e.currentTarget.value).format('$0,0.00');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make decimals optional.

```
numeral(e.currentTarget.value).format('$0,0.[00]');
```

Comment: Thanks Ercan that is an improvement but the format that I need is $80.00 when I use .format('$0,0.[00]') it does not format the value correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try the "input" eventListener. This will fire every time a new character is input.

```
var myInputElement = document.getElementById("element");

myInputElement.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  e.currentTarget.value = numeral(e.currentTarget.value).format('$0,0.00');
});
```

Comment: I tried the input event and that also did not work correctly. It does not allow users to type in more than one digit